# When catching Victini on Liberty Island is it ever possible that he will know Searing Shot?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

It is his first move in his learn set but since he is level 15 he only seems to know the four following moves in the learn set, Quick Attack, Endure, Incinerate, and Confusion. Searing Shot is the first move in the learn set and therefore is bumped out automatically by the next four (similar to leaving a pokemon in the daycare center).

My question is, has anyone caught him knowing Searing Shot? I wonder if I keep trying or if I kill him and come back, if he will ever have it or if he will have the same moves every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He will have the same moves every time.

You can still have a Victini with Searing Shot, however, by giving a Heart Scale to the Move Relearner.

Comment: I believe it's called the Move Relearner, and they are in Mistralton City.